# Anonymous function not being called

Tags: php

I'm using the next function, which I got it from [here](https://github.com/Xeoncross/micromvc/blob/master/Common.php)

```
/**
 * Attach (or remove) multiple callbacks to an event and trigger those callbacks when that event is called.
 *
 * @param string $event name
 * @param mixed $value the optional value to pass to each callback
 * @param mixed $callback the method or function to call - FALSE to remove all callbacks for event
 */
function event($event, $value = NULL, $callback = NULL)
{
    static $events;
    // Adding or removing a callback?
    if($callback !== NULL)
    {
        if($callback)
        {
            $events[$event][] = $callback;
        }
        else
        {
            unset($events[$event]);
        }
    }
    elseif(isset($events[$event])) // Fire a callback
    {
        foreach($events[$event] as $function)
        {
            $value = call_user_func($function, $value);
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

I'm adding some anonymous functions to be called when the event is executed.

```
event("Test", NULL ,function() { return "First Call";});
event("Test", NULL ,function() { return "Second Call";});
```

After that I'm doing a simple echo to see the result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
    $test =  event('Test');
    echo $test;
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The expected output would be

> "First Call Second Call"

but I'm only getting

> "Second Call"

At first I thought that the function was getting replaced instead of added to the array and I echoed the array and it seems that the call it's there as the output looked like this

> Array ( [0] => Closure Object ( ) [1] => Closure Object ( ) )

I've searched here and tried googling but couldn't find any answers that guide me into a solution.

Note: The server is using PHP Version **5.3.10**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only return 1 value at all

Try this

```
foreach($events[$event] as $function)
{
    $values[] = call_user_func($function, $value);
}
return implode(' ', $values);
```

Comment: Jesus, such a foolish mistake, can't belive didn't see that one...
Indeed it wasn't that the funcions wheren't beeing called it was only the fact i was seeing the last output of them. So much time wasted on this lol.
¡Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($events[$event] as $function)
    {
        $value .= call_user_func($function, $value).' ';
    }
    return $value;
```

Comment: I didn't said i was getting 2 times "Second Call", i was only getting one of them.
The answer provided by Shingo was the right one.

I this case i'm not overwriting the events because they are added on a multidimensional array, check the las output quoted on the answer.

The use of the static in this is case is to allow adding multiple callbacks to one event from diferent places.

Comment: I edited the answer, and sorry I went some extra miles.